# Second border to an element

Tags: html, css, border

I needed to make a second border without using images so my idea was to make another div inside the parent one ex:

```
<div class="box news">
    <div class="title">{l_news}</div>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" loop="-1" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="0">{news}</marquee>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
.box{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
}
.box div.title{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%-10px;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.border{
    width: 100%-2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

The **width: 100%-10px** worked the first time but not the second time. Why? Any suggestions for a way around that>

Comment: terrifying: you're probably not joking about that marquee tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do calculations like this in CSS. The only reason why the first rule worked is because the browser encounters a syntax error, and reverts back to the default setting. 
A `div` element's default behaviour is to stretch to the fullest available width.

For the `title` div I would recommend giving `.box` a `padding: 10px`.

I'm not 100% clear how you want the border but I think you should be able to work with `left: 2px; right: 2px; top: 2px; bottom: 2px` or a variation of it.

Comment: You are right but I need help about how to shrink a little bit the .border

Comment: @ItehnologicalDisexisting does using `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` not work? What is the problem?

Comment: You are going to be fighting against the current with this technique, why not just wrap the element instead of having a random empty div?

Comment: @Mad but then he would have to force a height on both elements, wouldn
't he?

Comment: No, the height of the inner element determines that of the wrapper.

Comment: @Mad true - I was confused by the  `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

you should use a single div and then give it this property `outline: 1px solid #d6d6d6;`. It will give the div an appearance of being within another... if that's what you want.

Comment: `outline` is a good solution here too, as long as you know it doesn't add to the height/width (which can actually be a good thing).

Comment: ...but unfortunately, there's no rounded corner support for `outline`.

Answer (score 2):

> The width: 100%-10px worked the first time but not the second time. Why?

It didn't "work", invalid property values are ignored. Take this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gR4GF/1/

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    width: Chuck Norris;
}
```

The width ends up as `50%`.

Anyways, if you want to use extra markup to add an extra border, don't use empty elements like `<div></div>`, instead **wrap** the element in the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/gR4GF/2/

```
<div class="box news">
    <div class="border">
        <div class="title">{l_news}</div>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" loop="-1" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="0">{news}</marquee>
    </div>
</div>
```

And yes, we're all cringing at that `<marquee>` - maybe you should check out a [javascript solution](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) ;)

Comment: Nonsense. Every browser worth its salt knows to interpret `Chuck Norris` as `1000%`.

Comment: @Pekka: It handles colors fonts and backgrounds too. The latest version of Chrome's entire default stylesheet is actually just `Chuck Norris`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use box-shadow or pseudo elements to create multiple borders:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

**Using :before**

```
.box{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
}

.box:before {
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   top: 2px;
   left: 2px;
   right: 2px;
   bottom: 2px;
   border: 2px solid #ffea00;
}
```

**Using Box Shadow**

```
.box{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
}
```

**How to create "100% - 10px"**

Block level elements (divs for example) by default take up the full width of their parent element. This is not the same thing as having a declared `width: 100%`. So, if you add `margin-left: 10px` to your div, (without declaring a width), you will effectively be giving is 100% width, minus the 10px left margin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a double border why not just set that on the "border" property? The extra div markup is not necessary.

Just do something like this:

```
border: 3px double #000;
```

Also if you want the ability to use operations in your CSS, look at using a css preprocessor like LESS or SASS.